# Issue in Query. Not working

Tags: mysql

```
<?php
        echo "Hello test <br>";
        $userid = $_GET['userid'];
        echo "your user userid is " . $userid . " &";
        $salt = $_GET['salt'];
        echo " your user salt is " . $salt;
        // Query for finding the data from db
        // Issue in query
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM test.test where id=" .$userid AND "salt=".$salt;
        echo "<br>" . $sql;
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if (!empty($result)) 
        {         
            echo "<br>Result Found";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "<br> Invalid link !";
        }
        // }
?>
```

My Query is not working properly. If I reduce my query to `id=".$userid` it works properly but if I add remaining portion its not working.

Comment: Use at least an editor with code highlighting. This will avoid you to stumble over simple syntax error like this one.

Answer (score 1):

The `$sql` line should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sauberlux_com.tbl_b2cuser where id=".$userid." AND salt=".$salt;
```

Comment: i have tried this one as well but its not working properly as well.

Comment: problem is when i run this query it gives me $result== false but it should be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sauberlux_com.tbl_b2cuser where id = $userid AND salt = $salt";
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sauberlux_com.tbl_b2cuser where id = $userid AND salt = '$salt' ";
```

Also you can refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) for sql injection